# Exporting part of SSRS report to separate pdf file

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to acheive having a summary section of a report saved into a separate pdf file. (Basically trying to avoid running two reports for the same data.)

Is it possible to export a particular part of an SSRS report to a separate pdf file?
I.e. If I had a summary table/rectangle within the main report, can it be saved separately from the main report? Having a pdf editor to split the file as suggested in:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27938046/ssrs-export-subreports-as-seperate-reports.html

I don't feel would save the time/hassle it costs to run the report twice.

Would this be an application for a linked report? I haven't used these, but it would seem a lot of information to pass through parameters (or am I missing something?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done in SSRS: you'll need special code like in your example that splits the pdf for you. If you just want a hands-free option, create two reports and have them run via subscription into the folders you need.